# Access Nested Array with Pug

Tags: express, nested, pug

I have the following that is being pulled froma MongoDB and I'm trying to display the "url" and "applications" in pug the data from url is displaying correctly but I'm having trouble accessing the data from "applications"

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5975cdfeb39f71f2fcc2a09d"),
        "url" : "http://www.opencolleges.edu.au",
        "applications" : [
                {
                        "name" : "AppNexus",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "AppNexus.svg",
                        "website" : "http://appnexus.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Advertising Networks"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "CloudFlare",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "CloudFlare.svg",
                        "website" : "http://www.cloudflare.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "CDN"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Crazy Egg",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "Crazy Egg.png",
                        "website" : "http://crazyegg.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Analytics"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Google AdSense",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "Google AdSense.svg",
                        "website" : "http://google.com/adsense",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Advertising Networks"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Google Analytics",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "UA",
                        "icon" : "Google Analytics.svg",
                        "website" : "http://google.com/analytics",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Analytics"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Google Font API",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "Google Font API.png",
                        "website" : "http://google.com/fonts",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Font Scripts"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Google Tag Manager",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "Google Tag Manager.png",
                        "website" : "http://www.google.com/tagmanager",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Tag Managers"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "New Relic",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "New Relic.png",
                        "website" : "http://newrelic.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Analytics"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Nginx",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "Nginx.svg",
                        "website" : "http://nginx.org/en",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Web Servers"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Optimizely",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "Optimizely.png",
                        "website" : "http://optimizely.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Analytics"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Sizmek",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "Sizmek.png",
                        "website" : "http://sizmek.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Advertising Networks"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Twitter Bootstrap",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "Twitter Bootstrap.png",
                        "website" : "http://getbootstrap.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Web Frameworks"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "VideoJS",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "VideoJS.png",
                        "website" : "http://videojs.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "Video Players"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "jQuery",
                        "confidence" : "100",
                        "version" : "",
                        "icon" : "jQuery.svg",
                        "website" : "http://jquery.com",
                        "categories" : [
                                "JavaScript Frameworks"
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "originalUrl" : "http://www.opencolleges.edu.au",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-26T23:23:19.756Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-07-24T10:37:50.247Z")
}
```

In the .pug file I use:

```
ul.list-group
            each tech, i in techs
                    li.list-group-item
                        h5 #{tech.originalUrl}
                        h5 #{tech.applications.name}
```

However the result for tech.applications.name returns null value and when I use tech.applications it returns [Object, Object] is it possible to access this using PUG?

Comment: same deal `each app in tech.applications`. Just like the outer data, it's also an array. You need to "iterate" it.

Comment: did the trick, but god i'm disliking pug